# Google Events API

Tags: arrays, json, api, events, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to code a website that includes events from a google calendar, and I was wondering if there is a good place to start to learn how to grab events from an existing calendar and then display them on my website? I know HTML, CSS, and Javascript, but I'm new to working with API's and JSON. Was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

## Resources

Check out [this quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/js) guide to get yourself started with the Google Calendar API. For more information related to the Events in the Calendar API [check this link](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

I hope this has helped you. Let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something. :)